# Checking if LINQ Where() returned anything before calling ToList() or Count()

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering if I do something like:

```
var results = source.Where(c => c.Name == "Whatever");
```

is there any way to check if the query returned anything before calling Count() or ToList() ? I know Where() executes lazily.

The data set returned might be huge and calling the above methods is quite time consuming.

*results* is never NULL either...

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you should be implementing skip and take on your queries to limit the return dataset.

Comment: Look up "deferred execution". The query won't run until you need something from it. You might want to try a smaller query if you think there may not be anything there, such as using the Take extension method

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. If `source` is empty, no, calling `Count` or `ToList` doesn't add an overhead over evaluating `source`, which you would do anyway if you wanted to know if `source` is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you just want to know if it's worthwhile to get the full result set this is never worth doing.

There are only two situations here:

1. There are no results for your query.  In this case, the query to check how many results there are will take exactly as long to execute, and return exactly as much information, as the *real* query.  You gain nothing (but also lose nothing) in this case.
2. There is at least one result to your query.  In this case you need to go back and execute the real query.  The net result is that you spent just as much time as you would have by not checking first, **but you also have the added cost of checking if there are results**.  That check means a round trip to the database, which is a non-trivial amount of time.

If you want to know if a query will contain any items it's *possible*.  (Just use the `Any` extension method.)  However, it's only *beneficial* if you don't need to know what the actual items are regardless of what the result of `Any` is.

It's also worth noting, as lazyberezovsky did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509690/1159478), that you also need to consider the race condition where the results of the query change after you call `Any`.

Comment: +1 from me for catch that there is no difference between getting zero rows or count equal to zero

Answer (score 3):

The only way to know if query will return something is executing that query. So, you can get results or check results count/existence. **BUT** In second case you can't be sure that further executions of query will produce same results.

Sample:

```
List<int> items = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var query = items.Where(i => i > 0);
// query is not executed at this point
var count = query.Count(); // first execution, returns 3
items.Clear();
var positiveItmes = query.ToList(); // ooop, no items here!
```

So, if you are sure that data will not change between queries (are you? completely?), you can use `Count()` or `Any()` before getting all data. In other case you have to load data with something like `ToList()`.

Comment: @Magnus well, that should do the job (I think it falls into part *if you are sure that data will not change between queries), but locking ranges is heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Sure just use Any it will tell you if there are any results.

```
results.Any();
```

As per MSDN:

This method does not return any one element of a collection. Instead, it determines whether the collection contains any elements.
The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.

[MSDN ANY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)

Comment: Won't Any() still execute the query?

Comment: @Bnicoll - There's no way to know if a query will return any results without executing it first.

Comment: This **will** execute the query. It'll do a `WHERE EXISTS`

Comment: `.Any()` will not execute *the* query if `source` is `IQueryable` -- it might well execute *a* query that provides the boolean result. Not the same.

Comment: There's no point in using this if you always execute the real query when it's true.  You save nothing.  If there was no data then getting the real query will be real fast (since there is no data).  If it is there, you're doing it anyway, so you just added the overhead of checking for nothing.  It's never a net win.

Comment: @Servy Your comment sound like the only correct answer to this question.

Comment: @Magnus Yep, just finished writing it up as [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14509877/1159478).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the useful suggestions and precisions. I ended up implementing this in my generic EF repository:

```
    public bool CheckExists(string tableName, string whereField, string whereValue)
    {
        string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0} WHERE {1} = {2}", tableName, whereField, whereValue);
        var count = _context.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(query).FirstOrDefault();
        if (count == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Much faster! :) I'm still executing a query, but since I don't ask LINQ/EF to translate the potential results to IENumerable's of complex class types, it seems to be OK.

Answer (score -2):

```
var any = (source.Where(c => c.Name == "Whatever").FirstOrDefault() != null);
```

FirstOrDefault will execute as a SELECT TOP 1 (LinqToSql)

Comment: 1) That's still executing the query 2) At least use `Any`

Comment: Comments please? The dataset will never be sent over the connection and you will get an answer to if any results are available.

Comment: As commented on the other answer, if you're going to pull the whole data set when any items exist you have saved nothing, since you're still doing the big query, and if it there are no items then executing the real query would be just as fast as this operation.